# Namespacing methods within a Ruby class

Tags: ruby, namespaces

I'm using Ruby's metaprogramming methods creating a bunch of methods within a class. Within the class `OmekaItem` there are a bunch of methods of this form `dc_title` and `dc_subject`, and there are a bunch of methods of this form `itm_field1` and `itm_field2`. I'd like to group those methods better. Ideally, given an instance of the class named `item`, I'd like call the methods this way:

- `item.dublin_core.title`
- `item.item_type_metadata.field`

and so on. Is there a way to do this?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000453/accessor-methods-for-specific-values-of-a-hash-in-ruby) has the code I'm working with.

Comment: as long as `item.dublin_core` returns an object that has a `title` method, that would work. You'd need to group all the methods for dublin_core (and related states) into a different class, and a state in OmekItem would be a dublin_core class instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like the following work for you?

```
class OmekaItem
  class DublinCore
    def initialize(omeka_item)
      @omeka_item = omeka_item
    end

    def title
      @omeka_item.dc_title
    end

    def subject
      @omeka_item.dc_subject
    end
  end

  class ItemTypeMetadata
    def initialize(omeka_item)
      @omeka_item = omeka_item
    end

    def field1
      @omeka_item.itm_field1
    end

    def field2
      @omeka_item.itm_field2
    end
  end

  def dublin_core
    @dublin_core ||= DublinCore.new(self)
  end

  def item_type_metadata
    @item_type_metadata ||= ItemTypeMetadata.new(self)
  end
end
```

The methods on `DublinCore` and `ItemTypeMetadata` could be dynamically generated using `define_method` as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. As you suggested, I used `define_method` to defined the actual methods for the `DublinCore` class. I thought I was going to have a hard time getting the `DublinCore` methods to refer back to the object that created it, which is the whole point. But the `object_id`s were the same, so it worked without any further changes. Ruby magic!